# Django login/register issue

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-users, django-database

I am new to Django and am building a database-driven website using PyCharm.

I am having an issue with users registering/logging in. What is happening is, when a user registers, I check the "Database" tab to the right, and the information will be passed into a table named "SavBlock_user", which will have the users name, password, etc.. Then, when I try to log in, it won't allow me to login due to incorrect username/password. However, if I try to login using a username/password from a different table named "auth_user" (like username: admin / password: admin), then I can successfully login. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Ideally, what I would like to do is completely remove the "SavBlock_user" table and strictly use "auth_user" for all of my users, but I'm not sure how to do this. I may have created a 'custom' user model back when I was learning the system, but I can't remember.

My files:

Project\register\forms.py

```
from django import forms
from SavBlock.models import * # <--- Contains User

''' Form for users to register '''

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        initial='myemail@savagez.com'
    )
    uso_validate = forms.BooleanField(
        label='Are you a PSMC member? (Chief, Uso, Anak)',
        initial=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

Project\register\views.py

```
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm


# Create your views here.
def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(response, 'register/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Project\SavBlock\models.py

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField("user name", max_length=50, default='')
    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    first_name = models.CharField("first name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField("last name", max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField("password", unique=True, max_length=50, default='')

    rank = {
        0: 'Supporter',
        1: 'Anak',
        2: 'Uso',
        3: 'Chief'
    }
    
    #TODO: FIT __INIT__
    '''
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
    '''
    # Magic method returns string of self
    def __str__(self):
        return f"User {self.first_name} {self.last_name} rank {self.rank}".strip()

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}".strip()


class Anak(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, tribe):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.tribe = tribe.title()
        self.rank = User.rank[1]


class Uso(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, tribe):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.tribe = tribe.title()
        self.rank = User.rank[2]
```

----EDIT----

I fixed the different user tables and basically reset the migrations. Now, all users are showing up under a single user table SavBlock_user. However, the login issue is still there.

[image: sqlite3.db]

Admin was created using the terminal manage.py createsuperuser command. I **am** able to login on the webpage using this account.

testing123 was created using the registration form. It pulls up a message that says "Please enter a correct username and password".

[image: Login Screenshot]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this solves my issue though. I still want to use my SavBlock.models User model that I created. Maybe I'm confused about how this works. Can you explain how the login process works and why it's using auth_user rather than SavBlock_user?

Comment: I don't think inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser` would be very complex to do... Furthermore looking at your user model it doesn't differ much from auth's user model so you can simply inherit from `AbstractUser`. Anyway I won't recommend using your model you don't even hash the password (which **is** done in auth's user models)...

Comment: If you would have read the documentation linked carefully you would also have noticed this section [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) which is how one would use their custom user models (How would you expect Django to magically know you use some custom user model if you don't specify it anywhere?...)

Comment: Thanks for your correct, and somewhat aggressive answer. I'm still learning. And yes, you're right, I missed that section but it does answer my question. I appreciate your help!